# Angular.js: Add a class to elements outside of the scope depending on the used route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I add a class outside of the scope? As you can see here I want to add a class to header, main and footer

```
<header class="{{pageClass}}"></header>
<main class="{{pageClass}}" ng-view></main>
<footer class="{{pageClass}}"></footer>
```

This is my routing and the controller:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/chapter/:title', {
        templateUrl: 'article.html',
        controller: 'article'
    })
    .when('/suche', {
        templateUrl: 'search.html',
        controller: 'search'
    })   
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/search'
    });

});

app.controller('article', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'normal';
});

app.controller('search', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'small';
});
```

Now I want to add the class 'normal' when the user has opened an article. If the user goes to the search-page, another class (i.e. 'small') should be added.

So there are always set a class to every three tags (header, main and footer). The difference is just which kind of routing is been used.
Hope I could explain what I try to achieve.

Comment: this should work..what else you want?

Comment: I just get the class on the main tag

Comment: just use parent controller. Can you provide a bit more markup with using controllers and ng-app?

Comment: I've just the ng-app in the html-tag and ng-view in the main tag. The above shown HTML-Code is the content of body. Nothing else. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be an `parent` controller to your `body` tag that will have `$scope.parent = {};` object which will have that `className`.

**Note**

> I've use `$scope.parent = {};` because child controller can directly
>   access `className` by doing `$scope.parent.className` Using Javascript
>   prototypal inheritance here

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="parent">
  <header ng-class="parent.className"></header>
  <main ng-class="parent.className" ng-view></main>
  <footer ng-class="parent.className"></footer>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('parent', function($scope) {
    $scope.parent = {};
});

app.controller('search', function($scope) {
    $scope.parent.pageClass = 'small';
});

app.controller('article', function($scope,) {
    $scope.parent.pageClass = 'normal';
});
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9yJVaMBUF9nEck7SrUku?p=preview)

Comment: @downvoter may I know reason behind downvote? so that I can improve myself..is there anything wrong with code..

Comment: @user3142695 take look at the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9yJVaMBUF9nEck7SrUku?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the class on a parent scope or on `$rootScope` if no other parent scope exists.

The scope of `ng-view` is only available to the tag itself and its children.

Change your controllers to:

```
app.controller('article', function( $rootScope ) {
    $rootScope.pageClass = 'normal';
});

app.controller('search', function( $rootScope ) {
    $rootScope .pageClass = 'small';
});
```

Comment: What should I prefer? Adding a parent controller or using rootScope?

Comment: If the property is intended for use in the whole application then it should be there. Usually not a good idea...

Comment: @Nayish if situation happens something like it then you should go for service/factory.. Don't go for $rootScope?

Comment: Not always... because in some cases the property is so important that tge service will be injected everywhere and will cause a need for useless controllers to simply inject the service to some dom...

Comment: @Nayish inject service to DOM? what you meant to say..?did you feel something wrong with mine answer?

Comment: I ment to say that not all DOM needs a controller... and no, I didn't... I usually comment when I downvote unless the answer is terrible

Comment: @Nayish AFAIK you also need to inject `$rootScope` while using it in controller

Comment: Nope... only in isolated scopes. Anything on rootScope can be used anywhere within `ng-app` views except for isolated scoped directives

Comment: You need to really read this http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/learn-how-to-use-scopes-properly-in-angularjs/ ..Don't go for $rootScope which are global & applicable everywhere in use service whenever you want you can inject it & use it

Comment: Again... I know... usually wrong to do so... and I wrote this... but there are always exclusions to the rules

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my app:

1. I have a main Controller that wraps everything.

   ```
   <html ng-controller="AppCtrl">
   <---- code --->
   <body onload="onLoad()" class="{{ viewClass }}">
       <div id="page" class="scale-fade-fast" ng-view></div>
   <---- code --->
   ```
2. Route config of main module:

   ```
   MainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
          $routeProvider
              .when('/path', {
                 viewClass: 'myPageClass',
                 templateUrl: 'path/to/tpl',
                 controller: 'AnotherCtrl'
              })
   <---- code --->
   ```
3. Listen on route change on main ctrl:

   ```
   MainApp.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.viewClass = 'defaultPageClass';
       $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(evt, current, previous){
           if(current.viewClass) $scope.viewClass = current.viewClass;
       });
   }]);
   ```